# Как сделать что бьі работали все три кнопки а не только bot.send_message(message.chat.id, useful_q)

Tags: python, telegram-bot

вот так?

```
import telebot
import random
from telebot import types
from collections import deque

def get_first_element_in_the_queue(array: list) -> str:
    first_element = array[0]
    array.rotate(-1)
    return first_element

f = open('/Users/marina/ukrwrite/ch.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF-8')
ch = f.read().split('\n')
f.close()

f = open('/Users/marina/ukrwrite/useful.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF-8')
useful = f.read().split('\n')
f.close()

f = open('/Users/marina/ukrwrite/ra.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF-8')
ra = f.read().split('\n')
f.close()

ch_q = deque(ch)
useful_q = deque(useful)
ra_q = deque(ra)

bot = telebot.TeleBot('611')

@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start(m, res=False):
    markup=types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item1=types.KeyboardButton("челендж")
    item2=types.KeyboardButton("корисне")
    item3 = types.KeyboardButton("рекомендовані авторки")
    markup.add(item1)
    markup.add(item2)
    markup.add(item3)
    bot.send_message(m.chat.id, 'Привіт. ',  reply_markup=markup)
    handle_text(message=None, useful_q=useful_q)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])

def handle_text(message, useful_q):
    if message.text.strip() == 'челендж':
        ch_q == get_first_element_in_the_queue(ch_q)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, ch_q)
    elif message.text.strip() == 'корисне':
        useful_q == get_first_element_in_the_queue(useful_q)
    try:
        useful_q == get_first_element_in_the_queue(useful_q)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, useful_q)
        except IndexError:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Список закончился. Начинаю заново.")
        useful_q = queue.Queue(maxsize=queue_size)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, useful_q)
    elif message.text.strip() == 'рекомендовані авторки':
        ra_q == get_first_element_in_the_queue(ra_q)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, ra_q)

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```